# Dropdown selected value is not showing after selection flask?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, jinja2

How to use HTML `<select>` dropdown list which is prepopulated from `flask - render_template`.

Here is the `<select>` dropdown list which is prepopulated from flask-jinja2.

```
<div>
    <select class="test-default" id="testTime">
        {% for option in options %}
        <option value={{ option }}>{{ option }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
```

Script in `test.html`,

```
function fetch_test_data(){
    let test = $("#testTime").val();
    axios({ 
        method:"get",
        url:"/test",
        params: {
            test
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        $(document.body).html(response.data)
    }); 
}
```

And `test.py` file - with app route and `options` for dropdown.

```
@app.route('/test', methods=["GET"])
@login_required
def transactions_view():
    options = ["0","7","14","30"]

    return render_template("test.html", options=options)
```

In the above case how to use `selected` attribute to display the selected value.

when a value is selected,
The correct value is returned to the flask and rendered back. But dropdown visualization/list shows the first value instead of selected value?

**What I have tried:**
I'm able to get `dropdown` `select` for defined dropdown.

`defined-dropdown` - for reference

```
<div>
    <select class="test-default" id="testTime">
    <option value=0>today</option>
    <option value=7>week</option>
    <option value=14>fortnight</option>
    <option value=30>month</option>
    </select>
</div>

{{ time }}
```

I'm able to use the above dropdown to this:

```
<div>
    <select class="test-default" id="testTime">
    <option value=0 {% if time == 0 %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>today</option>
    <option value=7 {% if time == 7 %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>week</option>
    <option value=14 {% if time == 14 %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>fortnight</option>
    <option value=30 {% if time == 30 %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>month</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Where `{{ time }}` is returned from test.py

```
@app.route('/test', methods=["GET"])
@login_required
def transactions_view():
    time = (request.args.get("test"))
    return render_template("test.html", time=time)
```

Comment: parse your variable value to int, eg: `int(time)`

Comment: @Zanthoxylum-piperitum why do you add a bounty to a question that you abandon afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the selected time in `transactions_view()` to the template and test each option's value during the rendering.

First, in `test.py` you have to modify `transactions_view()` like this:

```
@app.route('/test', methods=["GET"])
@login_required
def transactions_view():
    options = (
        (0, 'today'),
        (7, 'week'),
        (14, 'fortnight'),
        (30, 'month'),
    )
    default_time = 0
    selected_time = int(request.args.get('time', default_time))

    return render_template("test.html", options=options, selected_time=selected_time)
```

Here we have the `options` variable as a tuple of key-label pairs, and `selected_time` variable holds the value of the selected time from the `GET` request or a default value. Both variables have been passed to the `render_template` function so we can access them in the template file.

And in the `test.html` template file you have to modify the `for` loop like this:

```
<div>
  <select class="test-default" id="testTime">
    {% for time, label in options %}
    <option value="{{ time }}" {% if time == selected_time %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ label }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
</div>
```

Here we test each option's `time` value whether it is the selected time and set `selected` attribute accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion we should avoid letting our html/rendering logic leak into our routes/controller handlers. therefore, for the example above you should only make changes to your template html. lastly, i believe javascript is a better and more clean implementation rather than using jinja conditionals.

```html
<!--  /templates/time.html -->
{% 
   set time_lookup = { 
        0:  "Today",
        7:  "Week",
        14: "Fortnight",
        30: "Month",
    }
%}
<div>
    <select class="test-default" id="testTime">
        {% for option in options %}
           <option value={{ option }}>{{ time_lookup[option] }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
<script>

const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search); 
// current url and parse our query params "?test=201"

const timeParam = urlParams.get("time") || "0";
// default to 0

const option = document.querySelector("select.test-time option[value=" + timeParam + "]") 
// returns <option> HTMLElement where value === timeParam

option.setAttribute("selected", true)
// set <option selected="true"> on HTMLElement

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

axios obtains the response with the updated *time* parameter, however you will need to load the response, which is the updated HTML, to see the updated time.

You can update your *fetch_test_data* function as shown below to load the HTML response when the drop-down value changes.

```
function fetch_test_data(){
    let test = $("#testTime").val();
    axios({ 
        method:"get",
        url:"/test",
        params: {
            test
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        $(document.body).html(response.data)
    }); 
}
```

If using axios is not a requirement for you and you simply want to update the time, the following code will do just that without sending a request.

```
<span id=timelabel>Default Time</span>


<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script>

    var label = document.getElementById('timelabel');
    var dropdown = document.getElementById('testTime');

    $("#testTime").on("change",function (evt) {
        label.textContent = dropdown.value;
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Updated the question, please check